# How to use loops to instantiate and render objects/shapes using JavaScript and Canvas

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, canvas

Using Javascript and canvas, I'm trying to create a loop that will instantiate a new "ball" (a circle that comes on screen) and also add it to an array and if possible reprint it to the canvas. I want the loop to repeat 20 times, adding 20 objects/"balls" to the array, and also rendering it to the canvas. Right now what I have, or as far as I have been able to figure out, is how to manually instantiate a new ball, store it in an array, and render it. I haven't been able to figure out how to properly incorporate the loop to do it for me. Any advice will help, thank you.

```js
let ball1;
let ball2;

let balls=[];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600);
  ball1=new Ball();
  ball2=new Ball();
} 

function drawBackground() {
  background(80);
}

function draw() {
  drawBackground(); 

  balls.push(ball1);
  balls.push(ball2);
  balls[0].render();
  balls[1].render();
}

class Ball{
  constructor(){
    this.size=random(25,75);
    //colors
    this.r=random(0,255);
    this.g=random(0,255);
    this.b=random(0,255);

    //position
    this.xpos=random(20,780);
    this.ypos=random(20,580);
  }

  render(){
    fill(this.r,this.g,this.b);
    ellipse(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.size,this.size);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop and populate an array of "balls". You can call whatever method each instance of class `Ball` has from the array.

```js
let balls = [];

function setup(number_of_balls) {
  createCanvas(800, 600);
  for (let i=0; i<number_of_balls; i++){
    balls.push(new Ball())
  }
} 

function createCanvas(w, h) {
  console.log('canvas created!')
}

function draw(number_of_balls) {
  for (let i=0; i<number_of_balls; i++){
    balls[i].render()
  }
}

class Ball{
  constructor(){
    // construct the ball
  }
  render(){
    console.log('ball rendered')
  }
}

// initialize
setup(20)
draw(20)
```